# The right way to bind the model to save multiple records to a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Menusettings pages which displays all the menuname from the database(Menutable).I want to save all the details into MenuRole table.For that I think I have to iterate over each menuitem and store the details in the MenuRole table(Is it the correct method?).But the problem is I am getting MenuList as null.So I couldnot iterate over the menulist .Also I am not sure how can i bind the checkbox value to the MenuRole table.

**The view is**

[image: Menu iew]

**Model is**

```
public class MenuRoleVM
{
    public int? RoleId { get; set; }
    public SelectList RoleList { get; set; }
    public MenuRole MenuRole { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Menu> MenuList { get; set; }
}
 public partial class MenuRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MenuID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RoleID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TransactionTime { get; set; }
    public bool CanAdd { get; set; }
    public bool CanEdit { get; set; }
    public bool CanDelete { get; set; }
    public bool CanView { get; set; }

    public virtual Menu Menu { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}

 public partial class Menu
{
    public Menu()
    {
        this.MenuRoles = new HashSet<MenuRole>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public string NavigateUrl { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MenuRole> MenuRoles { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller for binding the View**

```
 public ActionResult Add()
    {
        var _menuRoleVM = new MenuRoleVM
         {
             RoleList = new SelectList(_db.Roles.ToList(), "Id", "RoleName"),
             MenuList = _db.Menus.Where(m => m.NavigateUrl != "#"),
             MenuRole = new MenuRole()
         };
        return View(_menuRoleVM);

    }
```

**HTML Markup of View**

```
@model SMS.Models.ViewModel.MenuRoleVM

@foreach (var item in Model.MenuList.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i }))
 {
   <tr>
       <td>
           <input type="checkbox" class="minimal checkAll" />
       </td>
       <td>@item.Data.MenuName</td>
       <td>
          @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MenuRole.CanAdd, new { @class = "minimal single" })
       </td>
       <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MenuRole.CanEdit, new { @class = "minimal single" })
       </td>
       <td>
         @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MenuRole.CanDelete, new { @class = "minimal single" })
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MenuRole.CanView, new { @class = "minimal single" })
        </td>

      </tr>
     }
```

Any help is highly appreciated?

Comment: Your looping through your collection of `Menu` but then trying to bind to the properties of `MenuRole` (of which there is only one). Your not binding anything to the properties of `MenuList`

Comment: So I think MenuRole should also be IEnumerable.Can you post how the viewmodel and Iteration in the Html markup shouldbe..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need view models that represent what you want to display/edit

```
public class MenuVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool CanAdd { get; set; }
  public bool CanEdit { get; set; }
  public bool CanDelete { get; set; }
  public bool CanView { get; set; }
}

public class MenuRoleVM
{
  public int? RoleId { get; set; }
  public SelectList RoleList { get; set; }
  public List<MenuVM> MenuList { get; set; }
}
```

and in the view

```
@model MenuRoleVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleId, Model.RoleList)
  for(int i = 0; i < Model.MenuList.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MenuList[i].ID)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MenuList[i].Name)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MenuList[i].CanAdd)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MenuList[i].CanEdit)
    ....
  }
  <input type="submit" ... />
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have a small concern for the above code.How will I populate `MenuName` from the `Menu table` into the `MenuVM` viewmodel

Comment: You have not given enough info to be certain of your database, but first initialize a new instance - `var model = new MenuRoleVM()`. Then `model.MenuList = db.Menus.Where(...).Select(m => new MenuV(){ ID = m.Id, Name = m.MenuName }).ToList();`

Comment: Yup..Thats it..I think now I can populate and bind the values correctly.I havent tried it though,will try it soon and will vote the answer.